# Documenting Varargs Appropriately for Javadoc

Tags: java, parameters, documentation, javadoc, optional-parameters

I'm using `varargs` in a method for optional parameters. Any suggestion for how best to document the method?

Here's a wonderfully contrived example:

```
/**
*
* @param consumption
*     liters of liquid consumed after last pee
* @param options
*   urgency
*       how badly you have to pee on a scale of 1-3,
*       3 being the highest (default 1)
*   bribe
*       what's a toilet worth to you? (default 0)
* @return waitTime
*    minutes until you'll be able to relieve yourself
*/
public integer whenCanIUseTheBathroom(int consumption, int... options){
    // Segment handling options, defining defaults/fallbacks
    int urgency = 1;
    int bribe = 0;
    if(options.length > 0) {
        urgency = options[0];
    }
    if(options.length == 2) {
        bribe = options[1];
    }

    // Segment determining one's fate
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I understood what your javadoc was trying to tell me I might find a clearer way of writing it ... perhaps you should give a usage example or define what a "subparam" is?

Comment: Apologies, "subparam" was a vague/convoluted reference to an option provided by the `options` parameter. I just improved the clarity of the sample code.

Comment: You're probably better off having explicit overloads -- possibly redirecting to a unified method that accepts all options, default or not.

Comment: It's not a good example. The 'options' parameter would be better as a bitmask, `EnumSet,` etc. Normally the varargs argument is just something you can have any number of *without* having to describe them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varargs are not usually used to implement optional parameters with different meanings because it does not support different types for the "subparams", offers poor refactoring support (want to insert a new "subparam" or remove an old one?), and is inflexible (you can't omit "urgency" while providing "bribe"). Therefore, there is no standard way to document them with javadoc, either.

Optional parameters are typically implemented using overloading (usually with delegation), or a variant of the builder pattern, which allows you to write:

```
new BathroomRequest(3).withBribe(2).compute();
```

For a more thorough discussion of that approach, see [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, item 2](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2).